# Accessing Cookies API from a React WebExtension

Tags: reactjs, cookies, firefox-addon-webextensions

## **Summary**

I'm trying to access the Cookies API from a WebExtension which uses React, but I don't know why, it throws a TypeException, as if `browser.cookies` did not exist.

I've checked permissions and the code is copy/pasted from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAllCookieStores)... but still I can't get it to work.

## **Exception:**

```
TypeError: browser.cookies is undefined
```

## **Code**

This is the main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Popup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { sessionId: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var getting = browser.cookies.getAllCookieStores(); // This throws "TypeError: browser.cookies is undefined"
        getting.then(logStores);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>My App</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }

    logStores(cookieStores) {
        for (let store of cookieStores) {
            console.log(`Cookie store: ${store.id}\n Tab IDs: ${store.tabIds}`);
        }
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Popup />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And this is the `manifest.json` with the according permissions:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "browser_style": true,
      "default_icon": {
        "48": "images/Watermelon-48.png",
        "96": "images/Watermelon-96.png"
      },
      "default_title": "MyApp",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": ["browser", "cookies","<all_urls>","tabs"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

could you replace

```
"permissions": ["browser", "cookies","<all_urls>","tabs"]
```

By

```
"permissions": ["browserSettings", "cookies","<all_urls>","tabs"]
```